# How to summarize a dynamic object column?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Say I have an `exceptions` table which I know contains some data like the below, where `details` is a dynamic object

| operation_id | details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"cause": "sometext"} |
| 1 | {"other_info": 240} |
| 1 | {"message": "blabal" } |
| 2 | {"cause": "some other text"} |
| 2 | {"other_info": 88} |
| 2 | {"message": "blabal2" } |

How can I query these results to be grouped by `operation_id`, but somehow aggregate everying in the `details` column, perhaps something like

| operation_id | details_1 | details_2 | details_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"cause": "sometext"} | {"other_info": 240} | {"message": "blabal" } |
| 2 | {"cause": "some other text"} | {"other_info": 88} | {"message": "blabal2" } |

or even just join all `details` into a single column

I tried doing it with `summarize`, but it just shows each entry on a separate line (since each `details` is unique):

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > now() - 10m
| summarize by operation_Id, dynamic_to_json(['details'])
```

Does anyone have any advice about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`make_bag()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-bag-aggfunction).

for example:

```
datatable(operation_id:int, details:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic({"cause": "sometext"}),
    1, dynamic({"other_info": 240}),
    1, dynamic({"message": "blabal" }),
    2, dynamic({"cause": "some other text"}),
    2, dynamic({"other_info": 88}),
    2, dynamic({"message": "blabal2" }),
]
| summarize details = make_bag(details) by operation_id
```

| operation_id | details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "cause": "sometext", "other_info": 240, "message": "blabal" } |
| 2 | { "cause": "some other text", "other_info": 88, "message": "blabal2" } |

Answer (score 1):

I also got it working like this (using [make_set()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction))

```
 exceptions
 | project 
     operation_Id,
     details
 | summarize Details=make_set(details) by operation_Id
```

Although it returns `details` as an array of objects rather than a merged object